# Bubble sort a pack of cards

Tags: c++, enums, bubble-sort

I have taken myself down a rabbit hole that I do not know how to get out of, I have created a deck of random cards. However, I now need to sort them firstly by suit then by rank in the order of my enum's. Firstly I can't figure out how to get elements from within the vector and within the enum, so I can compare them, secondly, I suspect this links to the first I'm not sure how to swap them, finally it would be nice to have a function for the bubble sort that I can call twice to first-order them by suit and then call again to order by card.

Here are the libraries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
using std::vector;
```

These are the structs and enum's:

```
enum Rank { ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE }; // aspects of the card
enum Suit { HEARTS, CLUBS, DIAMONDS, SPADES };                                                    // suits of the card

struct Card {                       //Card data numbers
    Rank rank;
    Suit suit;
};

struct Deck {                      // defines a card
    vector<Card> cards;            // All the cards
    int size = 5;                  // Max deck size
};
```

This is what generates a random card deck:

```
void initialize(Deck& deck, string stdno) {
    for (int count=0; count < deck.size; count++) { //creates a deck of cards
        Card card;
        string rcardstr = stdno.substr(rand() % 8, 1) + stdno.substr(rand() % 8, 1);
        int rcard = stoi(rcardstr) % 52;
        card.suit = static_cast<Suit>(rcard / 13);     //cast between the enumerator and the value
        card.rank = static_cast<Rank>(1 + rcard % 13);
        deck.cards.push_back(card); //Adds the card to the deck of cards
    }
}
```

This is my feeble attempts of a bubble sort before I realized my first two problems:

```
void bubble_sort(Deck& deck ){
    bool swapp = true;
    while (swapp) {
        swapp = false;
        for (int i=0; i < deck.size; i++) {
            if (deck.rank[0]
        }
    }
}
```

...And finally my main function:

```
int main() {
    string stdno="14398132";
    Deck my_deck;
    initialize(my_deck, stdno);
}
```

If someone would be willing to give me a few minutes of their time to explain where I need to look/what I need to learn I would be incredibly grateful and make sure to give the same time back to the community once I've become better at c++.

Comment: please explain what the purpose of that string stdno is

Comment: First, try overloading `operator<` for your `Card` class.  It can be free-standing or as a method in your class.  See what happens.  (In other words, most sorting algorithms need to know how to order your elements and use `operator<` to help with the ordering.)

Comment: stdno is a number that is used to generate a random card rank and suit.

Comment: With `operator<` defined for your `Card` class, you could do something like this:  `if (deck[i] < deck[i+1]) continue;`

Comment: well your random generator can generate 5 cards all the same. Its very odd. Why not just `rand()%52`, that can still generate repeats but at least its doesnt have all that strange magic

Comment: The order is just the value of enum e.g one = 0

Comment: me I would just store the number of the card in the deck, and have functions to return the suit and rank (%4 and %13) when needed, the compare function then becomes trivial

Comment: Your `Card` class has two members.  The ordering could be comparing rank first or suit.  Which is it or is it both?

Comment: First by suit then by rank Matthew

Comment: Implement your bubble-sort to mirror `std::ranges::sort`. You have a `Comp` to switch between ascending and descending and `Proj` to project different order of fields. You can use `std::tie` for that projection to order by suite, cared, suite+card or card+suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to access the members of the deck is to write:

```
deck.cards[i].rank
```

or

```
deck.cards[i].suit
```

You have multiple options for sorting.

1. Simply write two functions:

```
void bubble_sort_by_rank(Deck& deck ){
    bool swapp = true;
    while (swapp) {
        swapp = false;
        for (int i=0; i < deck.cards.size()-1; i++) {
            if (deck.cards[i+1].rank > deck.cards[i].rank){
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
void bubble_sort_by_suit(Deck& deck ){
    bool swapp = true;
    while (swapp) {
        swapp = false;
        for (int i=0; i < deck.cards.size()-1; i++) {
            if (deck.cards[i+1].suit > deck.cards[i].suit){
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Write one bubble sort function, but take the sort criteria as a parameter (which can be enum).
3. Write a single bubble sort function, but compare each card first by suit and if they were equal, then compare them by rank or just overload the operator< for your Card class as suggested in the comments. This is probably the preferred method and more efficient.

If you don't insist on using bubble sort, you can just use `std::sort` with a lambda function that compares your cards first by suit then by rank.

For swapping you should be able to use [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) or write a simple template function yourself:

```
template <class T>
void swap(T& x,T& y)
{
     T temp;
     temp=x;
     x=y;
     y=temp;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, an *ordering* function or method would be cleaner.

Comment: Thank you this is perfect, I will add a Pastebin to my question of the final code. That swap function is very useful, I'm glad you mentioned it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: agreed!